# Shopify Liquid - if product.template contains

Tags: content-management-system, logic, shopify, liquid

I am trying to retrieve the template for a specific product while NOT on the product template page. I am on the collection page and am trying to adjust the Quick shop feature to only show the add to cart for products no associated with a custom template. For example, I've assigned a 'consultation' template to a group of products. However because I am no longer on the product template page, the Quick shop doesn't recognize the consultation product. Any ideas on how I can make this work other than using tags, types and collections?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

On collection page , products for that collection are called in a loop, something like

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
...
{% assign prodtemplate =  product.template_suffix %}
{% if prodtemplate contains 'consultation' %}
{% else %}
//Add to Cart code
{% endif %}
...
{% endfor %}
```